# Why is Chrome not receiving my cookie?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I've got a webserver set up, and serving a route. When I hit it with `curl` I get:

```
$ curl -i -X POST http://dev.com:5000/user/check
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 40
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: session=eyJjaGVjayI6dHJ1ZX0.Dij_Ng.OL7a0pycpZgU45zEIzC5ZTfeCdk; Domain=.dev.com; HttpOnly; Path=/
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 15:03:18 GMT

{
  "result": null,
  "status": "ok"
}
```

When I hit it in Chrome, however, the debug console reports:

**General**

```
Request URL: http://dev.com:5000/user/check
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 15:04:10 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
Vary: Origin, Cookie
```

**Request Headers**

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
```

No cookie is returned. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I am testing similar on my localhost, and found the same issue.

I created a php page on my website `example.com` which responded with similar `Set-cookie` header containing `domain` and other values.

**Test 1**

I called that page as a `<script src="http://example.com/my.php">` from `localhost`.

Chrome network tab didn't show the `Set-cookie` header in `Response Headers`, but the **cookie was set**, which I confirmed in the **Application** tab in devtools.

**Test 2**

Also, while on this page, I made another request to the php page from console using `document.createElement('script')`, setting its `src` attribute and then appending that element to body.

But, the `Request Headers` **did not contain** any `Cookie` headers.

**Test 3**

I opened another tab, opened devtools, and then typed `http://example.com/my.php` and hit enter.

This time, the `Cookie` was **present** in `Request Headers`.

Also, in Test 1 and Test 2, the `Request Headers` are shown as **Provisional headers are shown**, but in Test 3, it is not so.

I wonder if that is an issue with the `domain` parameter.